# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' -Attribute Error

Tags: python, django

### views.py

*What is wrong in the 7th line*

```
@login_required
        def user_recommendation_list(request):
            #get request user reviewed wines
            user_reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_name=request.user.username).prefetch_related('wine')
            user_reviews_wine_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.wine.id, user_reviews))          
            #get request user cluster name (just the first one righ now)
            user_cluster_name =User.objects.get(username=request.user.username).cluster_set.first().name
```

Comment: because the last query is returning blank

Comment: `.cluster_set.first()` is returning `None`

Comment: I could not get it...here is my full code...

Comment: post your models too, for better understanding

Comment: I have uploaded the images.Please check it above!

Comment: Check this views and model of this repo...  https://github.com/sandeep135/winerecom/tree/master/reviews

Answer (score 0):

First, you can directly access the logged in user via request.user

```
user_cluster = request.user.cluster_set.first()
```

Then you should check if the user have at least one cluster assigned, as first may return `None` in that case

```
user_cluster_name = user_cluster.name if user_cluser else None
```

`user_cluster_name` will be None if the user have a cluster assigned otherwise it will be `None`

Comment: this is  giving the error 'Cluster matching query does not exist.'